# Sci-Fi short story about a woman travelling through the solar system?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space, soft-sci-fi

Very vague and choppy memories here, apologies. So I remember reading a short story some time ago about a woman. At one point she was in a cabin in the mountains I believe, then travels through the solar system through some sort of alternate reality system or dream state or something to visit her family on mars or something. Then travels to I want to say Jupiter, there is a portion where she describes swimming/flying through the gas clouds on a gaseous planet. Then I want to say through continuous space travel she is able to become omnipotent or all knowing or something. Possibly some time travel in there... Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54268/short-story-about-a-woman-that-travels-to-other-planets-read-online-recently-s

Answer (score 8):

Could it be ["The Gentle Seduction"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48297) by [Marc Stiegler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Stiegler)? If so, this was answered before, in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/54268/4495), [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32664/looking-for-a-story-about-a-girl-and-her-experience-with-technological-advances) and [this  one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48559/short-story-i-read-online-about-woman-who-lives-in-a-society-where-no-one-ages-a). You can read [the story](http://www.skyhunter.com/marcs/GentleSeduction.html) for free at the [author's website](http://www.skyhunter.com/marc.html).

Shamelessly stolen from one of the answers:

**Summary:** A technology-averse woman lives by Mt. Rainier in the State of Washington. Her husband dies, her dog dies. At the age of 82 she takes her first nanotech pill, for her aching back. One thing leads to another, and eventually:

> But in addition, the nanomachines in that system would continue to build. They would build machines and living flesh well suited to the conditions of the planet. And then the nanomachines would come back together into a single structure—not a needle now, but a communication bubble. Through the bubble and its instantaneous communication she could live across space. She could dwell at home near Jupiter yet roam among the stars.
>
> She was often one of the first humans Called to newly opened planets. Her wisdom from earth, her expertise from Jupiter, these made her invaluable as an explorer and a guide. As she had swum within the methane oceans, so now she swam in carbon dioxide atmospheres, or flew through liquid mercury. She imprinted herself upon organic synapses and silicon circuits light years from home, and lived in many places.
>
> Mentally she was bigger now than she had been at 25. The meaning of complexity had changed for her; she understood the laws of physics with the same simple clarity that she understood the rules of checkers. She could build a starship as easily as she could pitch a tent.